# Multiprocessing: Synchronizing Shared Data with GUI

Tags: dictionary, user-interface, events, multiprocessing, queue

I'm currently facing challenges in achieving my goal, and I'd appreciate some guidance.

SUMMARY:

- DataProducer1 (Sub1) and DataProducer2 (Sub2) generate data tuples, each with varying cycle times determined by their 'produce_data' functions and put them into their respective queues.
- DataProcessor's 'process_data' function handles data processing from the queues and prints the processed data.
- DataProcessor's 'handle_dynamic_logic' function then signals the event, retrieves and prints the processed data from the shared dictionary.
- The dynamic logic part is adaptable to processed data, though currently, no specific logic is implemented yet.
- The provided code is functional and executable in Thonny IDE on Windows. Additionally, the output is available for observation without execution.

GOAL:

- My objective is to synchronize data visualization with these processes without any delay by introducing another class and its function, utilizing a turtle-based or any GUI approach solely for displaying the data.

***MY CODE***

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Lock, Event, Manager
import time
import random
import turtle

class DataProcessor:
    def __init__(self, data_queue1, data_queue2, lock, event, shared_data):
        self.data_queue1 = data_queue1
        self.data_queue2 = data_queue2
        self.lock = lock
        self.event = event
        self.shared_data = shared_data
        self.data1_a = None
        self.data1_b = None
        self.data1_c = None
        self.data2_a = None
        self.data2_b = None
        self.data2_c = None

    def process_data(self):
        while True:
            with self.lock:
                if not self.data_queue1.empty():
                    self.shared_data['data1'] = self.data_queue1.get()
                    # Process data here
                    print(f"Processed data from Queue 1 : {self.shared_data['data1']}")
                    self.event.set() # Signal that processing is done

                if not self.data_queue2.empty():
                    self.shared_data['data2'] = self.data_queue2.get()
                    # Process data here
                    print(f"Processed data from Queue 2: {self.shared_data['data2']}")
                    self.event.set() # Signal that processing is done

    def handle_dynamic_logic(self):
        while True:
            self.event.wait() # Wait for processing to be done

            self.data1_a, self.data1_b, self.data1_c = self.shared_data['data1']
            self.data2_a, self.data2_b, self.data2_c = self.shared_data['data2']

            print(f"data1:   (A){self.data1_a}  (B){self.data1_b}  (C){self.data1_c}")
            print(f"data2:   (A){self.data2_a}  (B){self.data2_b}  (C){self.data2_c}")
            print(" ")
            
            # Add dynamic logic here based on the completion of data processing

            self.event.clear() # Reset the event flag
      
class DataProducer1:
    def __init__(self, data_queue, lock, event):
        self.data_queue = data_queue
        self.lock = lock
        self.event = event

    def produce_data(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            j = i + 10
            k = i - 5
            data_tuple = (i, j, k)

            with self.lock:
                self.event.clear()  # Clear the event before adding data
                self.data_queue.put(data_tuple)
                print(f"Sub1: {data_tuple}")

            self.event.wait()  # Wait for processing to be done            
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.5)) # Simulate variable processing time

class DataProducer2:
    def __init__(self, data_queue, lock, event):
        self.data_queue = data_queue
        self.lock = lock
        self.event = event

    def produce_data(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 5
            j = i + 15
            k = i - 10
            data_tuple = (i, j, k)

            with self.lock:
                self.event.clear()  # Clear the event before adding data
                self.data_queue.put(data_tuple)
                print(f"Sub2: {data_tuple}")

            self.event.wait()  # Wait for processing to be done            
            time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 1.5)) # Simulate variable processing time


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Manager() as manager:
        data_queue1 = Queue()
        data_queue2 = Queue()
        lock = Lock()
        event = Event()

        '''SHARED DATA DICTIONARY'''
        shared_data = manager.dict({'data1': (0, 0, 0), 'data2': (0, 0, 0)})

        '''PROCESS1'''
        processor = DataProcessor(data_queue1, data_queue2, lock, event, shared_data)
        process_processor = Process(target=processor.process_data)
        process_processor.start()
        
        '''PROCESS2'''
        dynamic_logic_handler = Process(target=processor.handle_dynamic_logic)
        dynamic_logic_handler.start()
        
        '''PROCESS3'''
        producer1 = DataProducer1(data_queue1, lock, event)
        process_producer1 = Process(target=producer1.produce_data)
        process_producer1.start()
        
        '''PROCESS4'''
        producer2 = DataProducer2(data_queue2, lock, event)
        process_producer2 = Process(target=producer2.produce_data)
        process_producer2.start()
        
        
        process_processor.join()
        dynamic_logic_handler.join()
        process_producer1.join()
        process_producer2.join()
```

***OUTPUT***

```
Sub1: (1, 11, -4)
Sub2: (5, 20, -5)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (1, 11, -4)
Processed data from Queue 2: (5, 20, -5)
data1:   (A)1  (B)11  (C)-4
data2:   (A)5  (B)20  (C)-5
 
Sub1: (2, 12, -3)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (2, 12, -3)
data1:   (A)2  (B)12  (C)-3
data2:   (A)5  (B)20  (C)-5
 
Sub1: (3, 13, -2)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (3, 13, -2)
data1:   (A)3  (B)13  (C)-2
data2:   (A)5  (B)20  (C)-5
 
Sub1: (4, 14, -1)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (4, 14, -1)
data1:   (A)4  (B)14  (C)-1
data2:   (A)5  (B)20  (C)-5
 
Sub1: (5, 15, 0)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (5, 15, 0)
data1:   (A)5  (B)15  (C)0
data2:   (A)5  (B)20  (C)-5
 
Sub2: (10, 25, 0)
Processed data from Queue 2: (10, 25, 0)
data1:   (A)5  (B)15  (C)0
data2:   (A)10  (B)25  (C)0
 
Sub1: (6, 16, 1)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (6, 16, 1)
data1:   (A)6  (B)16  (C)1
data2:   (A)10  (B)25  (C)0
 
Sub1: (7, 17, 2)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (7, 17, 2)
data1:   (A)7  (B)17  (C)2
data2:   (A)10  (B)25  (C)0
 
Sub1: (8, 18, 3)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (8, 18, 3)
data1:   (A)8  (B)18  (C)3
data2:   (A)10  (B)25  (C)0
 
Sub2: (15, 30, 5)
Processed data from Queue 2: (15, 30, 5)
data1:   (A)8  (B)18  (C)3
data2:   (A)15  (B)30  (C)5
 
Sub1: (9, 19, 4)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (9, 19, 4)
data1:   (A)9  (B)19  (C)4
data2:   (A)15  (B)30  (C)5
 
Sub1: (10, 20, 5)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (10, 20, 5)
data1:   (A)10  (B)20  (C)5
data2:   (A)15  (B)30  (C)5
 
Sub1: (11, 21, 6)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (11, 21, 6)
data1:   (A)11  (B)21  (C)6
data2:   (A)15  (B)30  (C)5
 
Sub1: (12, 22, 7)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (12, 22, 7)
data1:   (A)12  (B)22  (C)7
data2:   (A)15  (B)30  (C)5
 
Sub2: (20, 35, 10)
Processed data from Queue 2: (20, 35, 10)
data1:   (A)12  (B)22  (C)7
data2:   (A)20  (B)35  (C)10
 
Sub1: (13, 23, 8)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (13, 23, 8)
data1:   (A)13  (B)23  (C)8
data2:   (A)20  (B)35  (C)10
 
Sub1: (14, 24, 9)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (14, 24, 9)
data1:   (A)14  (B)24  (C)9
data2:   (A)20  (B)35  (C)10
 
Sub1: (15, 25, 10)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (15, 25, 10)
data1:   (A)15  (B)25  (C)10
data2:   (A)20  (B)35  (C)10
 
Sub1: (16, 26, 11)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (16, 26, 11)
data1:   (A)16  (B)26  (C)11
data2:   (A)20  (B)35  (C)10
 
Sub1: (17, 27, 12)
Processed data from Queue 1 : (17, 27, 12)
data1:   (A)17  (B)27  (C)12
data2:   (A)20  (B)35  (C)10
 
Sub2: (25, 40, 15)
Processed data from Queue 2: (25, 40, 15)
data1:   (A)17  (B)27  (C)12
data2:   (A)25  (B)40  (C)15
```